# Choose second dimension of array, but use whole first dimension

Tags: java

Let's say I have a two dimensional array defined as:

```
boolean[][] col = new boolean[8][3];
```

Now how would I go about accessing all 8 values from the first dimension from any of the 3 locations on the second dimension? For example, col[0] would do what I want, but reversed.

For further clarification, I need to know how to access one of the 3 arrays with 8 values in it, rather than one of the 8 arrays with 3 values in them.

Comment: Sorry, `col[0]` would do what?

Comment: There aren't any "values" on for example col[0], what exists in col[0] is an array of size 3 with 3 values stored in it.

Comment: `col[0]` is equivalent to `[false, false, false]`.  I'm not sure what you're asking, OP.

Comment: Exactly, I am trying to access the array with 8 values.

Comment: You cannot simply invert an array, you'll have to create another one.

Answer (score 0):

While this isn't exactly what I was looking for, I have found a computationally slow and large solution:

```
boolean[] getA(int k) {
    boolean[] buf = new boolean[8];
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        buf[i] = col[i][k];
    }
    return buf;
}
```